# State not updating in unit test of Formik form

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, formik, react-testing-library

I'm learning how to use React and Formik. I'm using writing some unit tests and I'm having an issue where my component does not get updated value of an updated state. This is my form.

```
const ItemForm = ({values, item}) = {
 const {amount} = item;
 const {saveItem } = itemProvider();
 const doSaveItem = () => {
     saveItem(values);
   };
  const editingBlock = isEditing ?
      <div>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="amount">Amount</InputLabel>
        <Field
          component={TextField}
          name="amount"
          id="amount"
          inputProps={{
            'aria-label': 'edit-amount'
          }}
        />
      </div>
  ) : (
    <div aria-label="amount">
        Amount:${amount}.00
    </div>
  </>

  return (
     <>
      <IconButton aria-label="Save" onClick={doSaveItem} type="submit">
        <CheckIcon />
      </IconButton>
      {editingBlock}
     </>);
};

}
```

```
const ItemListingFormik = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={item}
      children={(formProps) => <ItemForm {...formProps} item={item} />}
    />
  );
};
```

Then I have a unit test for testing that the amount (original amount is 25) gets updated (to 34) after I enter an amount in the input. This doesn't work and the amount doesn't get updated after pressing the Save. However, it does work if I change doSaveItem to:

```
const doSaveItem = () => {
  item.amount = values.amount;
  saveItem(item);
};
```

Does anyone know why this might be?
My unit test:

```
it('test', async () => {
   const sampleItem = {
    amount: '25'
   };
   render(
     <itemProvider>
        <ItemListingFormik item={sampleItem} />
     </itemProvider>
   );
   const amtInput = screen.getByLabelText('edit-amount');
   fireEvent.change(amtInput, { target: { value: "34" } });
   const saveBtn = screen.getByLabelText('Save');
   fireEvent.click(saveBtn);
   expect(screen.getByLabelText('amount')).toBe('Amount:$34.00')

});
```

Comment: Did you try using screen.debug() to debug?

Comment: yes, I did. Things are being rendered fine just "amount" is not being updated...

Comment: try instead of fireEvent.change to use userEvent.type: https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/ from what I see its a textfield.
also in addition dontr manipulate objects directly:  item.amount = values.amount;
use the spread operator to copy.

Comment: @Michael I tried the userEven.type too and that didn't work either